# What would be the correct design pattern to use

Tags: java, design-patterns

So I have a Generator interface:

```
public interface Generator
{
    public Generator getInstance(); (The problem is here - methods in interface can't be static)
    public Account generate() throws WalletInitializationException;
}
```

And 2 other classes which implements the interface.

Now I'd like to have a GeneratorFactory class that receives the class Class object, invokes the getInstance() method and returns the class object.

Something like this:

```
public class GeneratorFactory
{
    private GeneratorFactory()
    {
    }

    public static Generator getGenerator(Class<Generator> generatorClass)
    {
        return (Generator) generatorClass.getMethod("getInstance", null).invoke((Need to have instance) null, null); (Should be runtime error)
    }
}
```

But since the getInstance() method is an instance method and not a static method, I can't call invoke() with a null parameter for the instance.

I thought of doing an abstract class of a Factory which contains a getInstance() method and an abstract generate() method for the generators class to implement it, will that be the correct approach?

Comment: So, basically, you want a factory for factories?

Comment: Something like that, I want the coder to only have to deal with one factory to get the other instances (factories).

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I'm having a hard time understanding what you want to achieve. It could be helpful if you provide a little usecase, even if it's pseudocode. Btw. questions that are about design-patterns and so on fit in [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) much better in general. I'm not saying you won't get an answer on SO but people on SE are more willing to go into details when it's about design.

Comment: What about `return generatorClass.newInstance();` or `return generatorClass.newInstance().getInstance();` in `getGenerator()`? Could that work for you? You will have to `try`-`catch` possible `Exception`s or give the method a `throws` declaration.

Comment: And you don't want to use reflection in your getGenerator?

Comment: It isn't the case that the answer is inevitably a design pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up not using singleton. Just using a regular factory with the following method that uses reflection:

```
    public static Generator getGenerator(Class<? extends Generator> generatorClass)
    {
        try
        {
            return generatorClass.newInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```